# Why does boost::asio::ip::tcp::basic_stream_socket::available have a long runtime?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-beast

The method `boost::asio::ip::tcp::basic_stream_socket::available` takes about 3us to complete. This amount of time is not egregiously slow, but is still slower than I'd expect for a method call that just returns state. What is the reason it takes so long? Does it use locks? If so, do multiple calls in parallel experience lock contention with each other?

Comment: As with any performance related issues, the first question has to be "did you test an optimized release build or a (compiler default) unoptimized debug build"? Testing unoptimized builds is rather pointless.

Comment: I used the ```-O3``` flag to compile my code. For boost, I installed that using the default instructions at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html. That page doesn't discuss optimizations, but because the Boost library is mostly header-only, it's probably fairly moot.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to get the information since your original question didn't provide it and it's really common for people to ask about "why doesn't my code perform well?", just to find out that they didn't even enable the optimizer and doing so would have solved the problem.

Comment: Like sehe pointed out, this goes to a system call. And yeah there are locks in the socket subsystem. Ethernet cards never sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it doesn't really matter much. To answer the question directly, here's what is being done on reactive-sockets implementation (e.g. Linux), preprocessed and reformatted:

```
size_t available(socket_type s, boost::system::error_code& ec) {
    if (s == invalid_socket) {
        ec = boost::asio::error::bad_descriptor;
        return 0;
    }
    ioctl_arg_type value = 0;
    int result = error_wrapper(::ioctl(s, FIONREAD, &value), ec);
    if (result == 0)
        ec = boost::system::error_code();
    return ec ? static_cast<size_t>(0) : static_cast<size_t>(value);
}
```

As you can see, it should all inline to a direct `FIONREAD` `ioctl`, barring error conditions. That's pretty lean, and would not take less time if you did it directly, in case you want to check:

```
static inline size_t my_available(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, boost::system::error_code& ec) {
    auto s = socket.native_handle();
    if (s == -1) {
        ec = boost::asio::error::bad_descriptor;
        return 0;
    }
    int value = 0;
    if (auto err = ::ioctl(s, FIONREAD, &value))
        ec = boost::system::error_code(err, boost::asio::error::get_system_category());
    else
        ec = boost::system::error_code();
    return ec? value : 0;
}
```

### [Reactor Style Operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html)

If you want to wait until data is available and act at the first opportunity, then you can `async_wait` on the socket: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_wait.html

You can specify to wait for read/write availability, or when there's a pending error condition

Docs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html